# Browse File Path Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a DataGridView inside my Windows Form where I load app.config file data. This is the code that will load the data into the DGV:

```
  _settings = new List<AppSettingsClass>();

    doc.Load(Path.Combine(path, SelectConfigComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "app.config"));
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
    {
      var item = new AppSettingsClass
    {
      Key = nodes[i].Attributes[0].Value,
      Value = nodes[i].Attributes[1].Value
    };

      settings.Add(item);
    }
      BindDataGrid();
      dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

I have some columns that has file path as data. I want to create a browse button so that the user can select the path instead of entering this manually. Is that possible? If it is can some one explain how I can do that.

I know it should be inside this method, but I have no idea how I can do that:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
//INSIDE THIS
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be your method.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex == 2)
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = dialog.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand it, Where do I put this code inside the CellClick event? And is it possible to make this function work for one specific Cell and not all the cells inside the DGV?

Comment: Made some edits after testing it, try it now. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I have tried it, but when I click on any cell it wont do anything? Is there something wrong?

Comment: Have you added the event handler to the girdview?
It should only create the dialog window on the third cell of the second column, as you requested in the comments below.

Comment: Yes I do, but it wont show anything. So I have tried each cell it might be on the wrong position, but still nothing happen.

Comment: If you copy your designer code to a pastebin and send it to me, I'll have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137076/discussion-between-khaab-and-tamas-szabo).

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && dataGridView1["Key", e.RowIndex].Value?.ToString() == "SomePathKey")
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dataGridView1["Value", e.RowIndex].Value = dialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I give it one specific Cell, because I don't want to have this function in to all cells, just one cell.

Comment: The first if statement should be responsible for that.

Comment: @TamásSzabó My DGV has 2 columns, I want it on the second column in cell 3. How can I add that to it?

Comment: Make this the first if statement.
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex = 2)

Comment: @TamásSzabó I have tried it like this: _if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex = 2) dataGridView1["Key", e.RowIndex].Value?.ToString() == "SomePathKey")_ but it gives me a error.

Comment: I'll make an answer with the whole solution.

Comment: @TamásSzabó Yes please, I would really appreciate it!